# Throwing exceptions and notifying the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I've recently joined an asp.net mvc project well under way where there isnt much consistency in dealing with exceptions in the controller; some devs return data to the client to let the user know whats wrong, others throw them back so they get to the server-level handler that processes and logs them - without letting the user know whats up.

It seems obvious to me that both approaches are wrong on their own, and need to complement each other instead; what I'm stuck at, is how to do that. I assume the eventual exception handler / logger could redirect the user to an error webpage upon catching something particularly nasty, but that limits the mechanism to just severe stuff.

I'm kind of looking for a way to do both "throw" and "return ..." at a time when I catch an exception, so I get it sorted and logged server side and get data client side that lets me tell the user there's been a hiccup.

My expertise with asp.net is very limited, and while I believe I understand mvc enough for it to not be an issue, this is kind of a "what is the best practice?" question from someone working with people who dont bother with best practices much.

Comment: The fact that you are worrying about this alone makes you a good addition to the team. But make sure you make your teammates see the importance of this too, otherwise you'll be the only one trying to make stuff better while the others keep breaking it again.

Comment: I agree with Mario.  Addressing your concern with your team is important.  If you feel that you have the better methodology for dealing with exceptions, then share it with your team, as it will better the product in the long run.  Having a casual discussion with them may also reveal their thought process and things that you may have overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good project called Elmah for logging errors and exceptions in ASP.NET applications. You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

> ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide
>   error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be
>   dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all
>   ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for
>   re-compilation or re-deployment.
>
> Once ELMAH has been dropped into a running web application and
>   configured appropriately, you get the following facilities without
>   changing a single line of your code:
>
> - Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely
>     view the entire log of recoded exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view
>     the full details of any one logged exception, including colored stack
>     traces.
> - In many cases, you can review the original yellow screen of
>     death that ASP.NET generated for a given exception, even with
>     customErrors mode turned off.
> - An e-mail notification of each error at
>     the time it occurs.
> - An RSS feed of the last 15 errors from the log.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC application that I am working on implements the `Application_Error` in the `Global.asax` to handle exceptions thrown from the application and then redirects the user to a standard error page.  The Controller for the error page handles the logging as well as displays just enough information about the error to allow a support person to find their session in the system and help resolve any issues.